# Why can't I get a specific object from this JSON document on Android?

Tags: android, json, polyline

I want to get polylines from a `JSONObject` but the following code doesn't work.

```
JSONObject poly = steps.getJSONObject("polyline");
```

I get this error:

> org.json.JSONException: No value for polyline

this code works fine

```
JSONArray legs = routes.getJSONArray("legs");
JSONObject steps = legs.getJSONObject(0);
JSONObject endLoc = steps.getJSONObject("end_location");
JSONObject duration = steps.getJSONObject("duration");
```

The incoming JSON document is

```
{
  "duration": {
    "value": 363,
    "text": "6 mins"
  },
  "distance": {
    "value": 506,
    "text": "0.5 km"
  },
  "end_location": {
    "lng": 11.48949,
    "lat": 53.52159
  },
  "start_address": "PCH30, 19079 Banzkow, Germany",
  "end_address": "PCH30, 19079 Banzkow, Germany",
  "start_location": {
    "lng": 11.48189,
    "lat": 53.52114
  },
  "via_waypoint": [

  ],
  "steps": [
    {
      "html_instructions": "Head <b>east<\/b> on <b>PCH30<\/b><div style=\"font-size:0.9em\">Destination will be on the left<\/div>",
      "duration": {
        "value": 363,
        "text": "6 mins"
      },
      "distance": {
        "value": 506,
        "text": "0.5 km"
      },
      "end_location": {
        "lng": 11.48949,
        "lat": 53.52159
      },
      "polyline": {
        "points": "cjteIypaeAGqBKaEGaBC{@A_AM{EMwGMwFIsDC}@"
      },
      "travel_mode": "WALKING",
      "start_location": {
        "lng": 11.48189,
        "lat": 53.52114
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And the complete code to get the `JSONObject`

```
StringBuilder urlString = new StringBuilder();
urlString.append("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?");
urlString.append("origin=");// from
urlString.append(Double.toString((double) gpAlt.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6));
urlString.append(",");
urlString.append(Double.toString((double) gpAlt.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6));
urlString.append("&destination=");// to
urlString.append(Double.toString((double) gpNeu.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6));
urlString.append(",");
urlString.append(Double.toString((double) gpNeu.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6));
urlString.append("&mode=walking&sensor=true");
Log.d("xxx", "URL=" + urlString.toString());

urlConnection = null;
URL url = null;

url = new URL(urlString.toString());
urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
urlConnection.connect();

InputStream inStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStream));

String temp, response = "";
while ((temp = bReader.readLine()) != null) 
{
    response += temp;
}

bReader.close();
inStream.close();
urlConnection.disconnect();

JSONObject object = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(response).nextValue();
JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("routes");
JSONObject routes = array.getJSONObject(0);
String summary = routes.getString("summary");
JSONArray legs = routes.getJSONArray("legs");
JSONObject steps = legs.getJSONObject(0);
JSONObject poly = steps.getJSONObject("polyline");
```

Comment: i think you will have some other issue in your current code bez as code shared here by you is perfect from my side to get polyline value fron json string.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the JSON you show there is incorrect, what you would need to do to get it is

```
JSONArray steps = routes.getJSONArray("steps");
JSONObject obj = steps.getJSONObject(0);
JSONObject poly = obj.getJSONObject("polyline");
```